# TreeView without RootNode in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, treeview, hierarchy

I have a HierarchicalDataTemplate that is the ItemSource of my TreeView. When the TreeView displays the data he has a rootnode. How can i remove the rootnode?

HierarchicalDataTemplate:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="cards" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=child::node()}">
        <TextBlock Text="Root"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="category" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=child::node()}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="card">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=./title}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="dataxml" XPath="root/cards" />

</Window.Resources>
```

TreeView:

```
<TreeView Name="treeViewCategory" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataxml}, XPath=.}"/>
```

XML:

```
<root>
  <cards>
    <category name="Categoryname">
      <card>
        <title>something</title>
        ...
        .
      </card>
      <category name="SubCategory">
        <card>
          <title>something else</title>
          ..
          ...
        </card>
      </category>
    </category>
    <card>
      <title>text</title>
      ...
      ..
    </card>
  </cards>
</root>
```

actual view:

```
o Root
    o Categoryname
        - something
        o SubCategory
            - something else
    - text
```

as it should be:

```
o Categoryname
    - something
    o SubCategory
        - something else
- text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go one step deeper when you assign the ItemsSource of the TreeView itself so that the children of your root become the items for the tree view.

Answer (score 0):

thx H.B. works perfect with:

```
<TreeView Name="treeViewCategory" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataxml}, XPath=./*}" />
```

i have always tried to change the source of the XmlDataProvider. haven´t imagine that i should change the Path at the TreeView :-(

why does it matter?

Comment: Great! I have not done anything with XmlDataProviders or XPath so far so i could not provide the code, good to see you managed to do apply what i said yourself :) Edit: About your added question, i do not know that sorry, it is weird isn't it....